# os.listdir throws Error 5 (IO Error) when in background

Tags: python, linux, fork, listdir

I am currently writing a plugin-based server for the VK social network. The plugin system is YAPSY, and the process is being backgrounded using `os.fork()`.

I have written a file server plugin for the said server. It works just fine after I launch it, but when I close the terminal session I used to launch it (I run it as root), the `LIST` command, which used to return the file/folder list just fine, begins to throw `[Errno 5] Input/output error`.

I am using `os.listdir` for getting the folder content as follows:

```
elif cmd == u'list':
            flist = os.listdir(self.cwd+'/'+('' if len(args)==0 else args[0]))
            otp = "Listing of "+(self.cwd.replace(self.topdirpath, "<root>") if len(args) == 0 else self.cwd.replace(self.topdirpath, "<root>")+"/"+args[0])+':\n'
            num = 0
            flist.sort()
            for fi in flist:
                otp += "["+str(num)+"] "+('-DIR- ' if os.path.isdir(self.cwd+'/'+('' if len(args)==0 else args[0])+'/'+fi) else '')+str(fi)+"\n"
                num += 1
            self.fSay(otp,vk,'200 LIST OK')
            return True
```

([filesvr.py Line 154](https://bitbucket.org/vladkorotnev/aklongpollserver/src/5d3d21a7827982df0ea9bdaa54fcd51a2fb84d7e/aklpplugin/filesvr/filesvr.py?at=master#cl-154))

While I didn't close the SSH session that I started the server from, it works just fine:

```
>> #$list
<< Listing of <root>:
[0] -DIR- AniArt
[1] -DIR- gifs
[2] -DIR- inbox
```

However once I log off SSH, things go weird:

```
>> #$list
<< libakcore longpoll server
There was an error processing your request. More info:
[Errno 5] Input/output error
```

Since no change was done to the folder contents, and it is accessible manually from the same user, I have no idea except for that the problem is in either `os.fork()` or `os.listdir()` or possibly both at the same time. However it is certain that it doesn't matter whether I call it from a separate thread or right from the forked-off server thread.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it turned out to be related to the `print` command!

Everything my server sent to me using the `fSay` went to the `fLog` as well. Wrapping the `print` inside `fLog` made all problems go away.

Things get really weird sometimes.